# csv to responsive table with custom property

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

so we have here a working csv file to html table conversion but the only thing stopping us it to be responsive is with this logic appending a custom data attribute on its respective `td`. please see image here : http://www.evernote.com/shard/s605/sh/523b17cf-0230-4d92-8a4b-34fee682f5d8/4201e925b3a054b0508f6d97d6f6106b

this is our current code html:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
 <script src ="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/PapaParse/4.1.2/papaparse.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="here allBorder hor template3 headColor"></div>
```

jquery / javascript :

```
function arrayToTable(tableData) {
var table = $('<table></table>');

 $(tableData).each(function (i, rowData) {
 var row = $('<tr></tr>');

$(rowData).each(function (j, cellData) {
 row.append($('<td>'+cellData+'</td>'));
});

   table.append(row);
        });
        return table;
    }

    setTimeout(function(){ 
     var y = $('.here tr td');
     var x = $('.here tr:first-child td'); 
       y.attr('data-column',x.text().split(/(?=[A-Z])/).join(" "));
    },1000);

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/162656/csv_data.csv",
        crossDomain: true,
        contentType:'html',
        success: function (data) {
            $('.here').append(arrayToTable(Papa.parse(data).data));
        }
    });
```

our working sample with error on jsbin : http://jsbin.com/xoligaleco/edit?html,js,output#J:L10

could someone help us with this thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [$.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each) to change data-column for each column like,

```
setTimeout(function() {
  var y = $('.here tr td');
  $(y).each(function(j){
     $(this).attr('data-column',$('.here tr:first-child td:eq(' + (j % 3) + ')').text());
  })
}, 1000);
```

And instead of using settimeout add data-column attr after appending your table like,

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/162656/csv_data.csv",
  crossDomain: true,
  contentType: 'html',
  success: function(data) {
    $('.here').append(arrayToTable(Papa.parse(data).data));
    var y = $('.here tr td');
    $(y).each(function(j){
       $(this).attr('data-column',$('.here tr:first-child td:eq(' + (j % 3) + ')').text());
    });
  }
});
```

I have made change to column left padding.

**[Jsbin demo](http://output.jsbin.com/dozilipila)**

Comment: Welcome Dear :)